# what you call a person who creates exam paper

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I need to know a single word for a person who creates exams/question papers

Comment: Why do you need to know? Can you also give a sentence in which this word would appear?

Comment: Whether you needed something like "examiner" or "creator" or "writer" or "author" or 17 other terms would depend on context. What is your context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English, SETTER is someone who decides or organises something as a part of a job, e.g. Who's the question setter for the quiz night? Internet is flooded with instructions for paper setters/ question setters about their DOs and DON'Ts. So you can try

- PAPER SETTER
- QUESTION SETTER
- EXAMINATION SETTER

That's fine and appropriate.

Comment: Yes. In Britain, and countries in the British Commonwealth, an examination setter is someone who creates examination papers. I don't know if the term is used elsewhere.

Comment: Good suggestion, Examination setter! It must be added to the entry as well.

Comment: Paper setter sounds very tacky. there is no class to it. Bone setter, paper setter etc. We should come up new word if we are not able to discover an appropriate word.

Comment: Till such time let us accede to the status quo

Answer (score 0):

"Examiner", or "test author" if the person who created/wrote the exam is different from the person who actually gave it to the test takers.

Comment: ‘Test author’ sounds like part of a process that ends up in a real author. Doesn’t sound like someone who writes exam papers.